# Apply json config file using parse_args() in pycharm

Tags: python, parsing, pycharm, argparse, pytorch

I'm running sequence to sequence code in git, but I got error about parse_args().
my code is like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--config",
    help="path to json config",
    required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
config_file_path = args.config
config = read_config(config_file_path)
experiment_name = hyperparam_string(config)
```

my config file is like this :

```
{
  "training": {
    "optimizer": "adam",
    "clip_c": 1,
    "lrate": 0.0002,
  },
  "management": {
    "monitor_loss": 1000,
    "print_samples": 20000
  }
```

When I run

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Pycharm raises error

```
pydevconsole.py: error: argument --config is required
```

I'd like to know that run this code through pycharm applying json config file.

I have searched in google since yesterday, but I can't find it.

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args = parser.parse_args()` parses the `sys.argv[1:]` list, which is provided to the interpreter from the operating system shell - ie. from the commandline.

```
$:python prog.py --config afilename
```

You can also do

```
args = parser.parse_args(['--config', 'afilename'])
```

this handy during testing.

It also helps to:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust this in the run configuration for your script; where you can pass it some parameters.

Go to `Run > Edit configurations...` in the menu, then add your parameters in the box.

[image]

The [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-python.html#d293363e39) shows you how to set it up, just make sure you use `"` around the values.